# Non-Browser Automation Testing with Protractor

Tags: gruntjs, protractor

Can Protractor be used to test non-browser based activities (such as windows pop-ups, windows explorer file selection or desktop icon selections) for automation scripting?

Answer (score 0):

protractor is for e2e testing for angular apps using web browser drivers via selenium

Comment: I understand.  But I was wondering if anyone knew a way for protractor to interface with windows.

Comment: not using the protractor api itself but you can use a third party library with a lot of tweaking like robot.js for desktop automation. but personally id recommend avoid doing that and see if the developers can add functionality so you can just insert the path of the file in an input field that you want to for instance upload.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I think I will just switch to eclipse and import sikuli to test the desktop and import selenium to test the browser